# How do I force TDS for iOS to update achievements in Game Center?

Tags: ios, star-wars-tiny-death-star, game-center

I am having problems getting my achievements in TDS to register in Game Center.

I can't get the "Build 50 levels" achievement, despite me already having built 65 levels.
[image: Achievement]
[image: Levels]

Strangely, after I bought Hoth Luke, the "Set of Rebel Heroes" achievement somehow activated (you can see it on the first screenshot). It is strange, because I either already had all the rebel heroes or only like a half of them - it depends on what exactly the game means.

[image: Heroes1]
[image: Heroes2]

Is there any way to force an update to the achievements in Game Center?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking.  I'm going to assume you are asking if there is a way to force an update to the achievements?  I've edited the post to make it reflect this. I also see that you are using iOS6.  Achievements seem to work better for me on iOS7 than they ever did on iOS6.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to yours, in that some of my achievements did not unlock after fulfilling the criteria. If I remember correctly, I think the buggy achievements were different from yours.

I was playing TDS on my old iPhone 4S (on iOS 7), and I think I built like 50+ floors but some achievements just refused to unlock. Then I got a new iPhone 5s, and started playing TDS from the ground up but using the same Game Center login.

In my new TDS game, I've already unlocked some of those achievements, and the rest of the unlocked achievements became unlocked on my 2nd run through the game.

So if it bugs you that you can't get all those achievements even after fulfilling the criteria, you can try resetting the game and using your same Game Center account to play the new game.

Comment: Then this disproves the theory that using iOS6 causes these problems...

Comment: @Ugh It could still be a problem related to older hardware.  What phone are you playing on?

Comment: 4S. Anyway they should fix it

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, Rebel Heroes ONLY refers to the 3 aliens you see at the bottom of your screen shot.  Specifically Akbar, Chewie, and Wicket.

For whatever reason, Han, Luke, Lando, and Leia are not considered heroes by the developers.  They are Men and Ladies of the Rebellion respectively.

As for why it unlocked when you purchased a different bitizen . . . My suspicion is that the achievements run a check whenever a new character is unlocked.

Game Center has always been plagued by oddities such as this, and sometimes it doesn't update if you get an achievement when you are not: signed in; on Wi-fi; or receiving cellular data.

Make certain that you are signed into Game Center, and that it confirms your log-in.  Then, try to build another level.  See if this fixes the problem.

It's the only way I can think of to possibly force an update.

Comment: "Build" like just purchase it or wait until it's built?

Comment: Just purchase I believe.

Comment: I've already purchased one Food level ~12 hours ago, and I'm sure everything was okay with my internet connection, but I'll try again soon and write there

Comment: It's a theory. It also might not appear until it completes construction.

Comment: I understand, but it won't hurt to confirm or disprove it.
I made sure I'm logged in Game Center and connected to internet and added another Food level. No reaction. The first level still needs ~5 hours to be finished

Comment: Nope, nothing happened after the first Food level was built

Comment: Oh well, that's why it was a theory.