# Why don't my achievements unlock in TDS?

Tags: achievements, star-wars-tiny-death-star

Rebel hero - capture a rebel hero
All level types - create one of each level type
Imperial level - build an imperial level

I have been playing the game for months, have 79 total levels, I've definitely achieved these trophies. Is there a known reason why they wouldn't be unlocking? All of the other trophies have.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common theme.  People have been complaining that nothing unlocks the achievements.  There is no known reason.  The only thing I can say, make certain that you are playing with an internet connection when you achieve those goals.

Comment: Thanks, at least others are having the same issue and it's not just me. Perhaps a fix will be on the way. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: No problem.  Check out http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149371/how-do-i-force-tds-for-ios-to-update-achievements-in-game-center?rq=1